# Google Cloud Firestore: Query regular Expression

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using google firebase's firestore. I was wondering if there was a way to query for documents where a property/field matches a regex. Something like this:

```
var username_regex = /^[a-z0-9\-\_\.]{3,}$/;
firebase.firestore().collection('users')
.where("username", "==", username_regex)
.get()
```

Is this possible yet? if not, how likely is it that google could implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Firestore rule that will allow you to read only valid usernames:

```
match /users/{userID} {
  allow read: if resource.data.username.matches('^[a-z0-9-_.]{3,30}$');
}
```